# Why is that we can access only 1MB in 16bit real mode?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, bios, real-mode

I can't understand why we can only access 1MB of memory in the 16bit real mode. Does the 1MB restriction denotes the memory access? I know that when a system starts we are limited to 16bit registers due to backward compatability, but why the restriction to memory and how?

Comment: In the case of MSDOS, there was/is [expanded memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expanded_memory) , or [extended memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_memory) , or as mentioned below, [msdos extenders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_extender) .

Comment: Starting with an Intel 80386 in the 16 bit real mode we can use 32 Bit register together with a register size and/or address size prefix and within the 16 bit protected-mode we can address 4 GB of memory. The limit ends with Intel 80286.

Comment: For 286 and later processors, 16 bit real mode can reach another 65,520 bytes just beyond the 1 MB boundary (for a PC/AT this depends on the A20 setting) [high memory area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_memory_area)

Comment: In addition to rcgldr, accessing above 1mb occurs on 286+ because there are more than 20 address lines on the CPU. The A20 gate was created as a way to to turn on/off the 20th (zero based) address line. At startup the A20 address line is off to remain compatible with 8086. If it is turned on you can access the area above 1mb (upto FFFF<<4+FFFF=10FFEF) otherwise accessing memory above FFFFF results in wrap around to address 00000. The A20 line has to be enabled in protected mode otherwise all addresses that have the 21st bit set will be unavailable and map to to addresses 1mb lower in memory.

Answer (score 3):

As per [Real-Mode Memory Management by Yariv Kaplan](http://www.internals.com/articles/protmode/realmode.htm)

A processor running in real-mode can exploit only the lowest 20 bits of its address bus and is therefore limited to the meagre 1MB memory space of the 8086.

Comment: also, you can refer to Gustavo's Duarte [blog](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/).

Comment: 8086 Address bus has only 20 bits right?

Comment: correct. "A 20-bit external address bus provides a 1 MB physical address space (2^20 = 1,048,576)." [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086#Buses_and_operation)

Comment: @VelRaj - Yes, it is a hardware limitation. This is from the 1970's when chips had only 40-pins! See [8086 pinout](http://comptutorkg2pg.blogspot.se/2011/11/pin-diagram-0f-8086-microprocessor-or.html).

Comment: To add more detail. On 8086 the 16-bit segment register was shifted left 4 bits and added to the 16-bit address operand, giving a 20-bit address. Consequently there were numerous ways to access the same physical address, as the physical range overlaps. Things moved on from there with 32 bit processors to use segment descriptor tables, rather than the segment registers directly.

Answer (score 2):

the address was computed by taking the segment shifted left 4 and add the offset. 20 bits of address giving 1MB of address space.  There was an additional signal or signals (google the pinout of the 8088 or 8086) to distinguish between a memory cycle and an I/O cycle basically doubling the address space (21 bits if you want to think of it that way) but they were tied to specific instructions (non-I/O were mem and I/O were I/O) and the I/O space didnt use the whole 20 bits.

Using the I/O space for register access in a peripheral there were memory extenders that sat in the 1MB address space and had more than 1MB behind them but you could only see 1MB at a time, using the control registers you specified what 1MB to look and and that was all tied into libraries or the operating system.  this is exactly how video cards and other peripherals work today in a computer, your entire pci(e) space is very small 1GB or 2GB depending on how old it is, and all of your pci peripherals have to share that space, so your video card in particular has to either generate the pixels for you by some other means (draw me a polygon like this at this place with this shading) or swap out access to the ram for the main processor to access the pixels.

peripherals back then worked that way as well (video cards, etc), but you didnt have pci.  there was a boot scheme used to find bios roms on the peripherals, and from there you used bios calls to talk to or switch out banks in that peripherals space which that peripheral owned.

the intel world was constantly beat up by the motorola world with their flat address space that we still live in this illusion of a flat space, and the assumption that segment offset is bad, but the reality is everywhere now we use a segment offset type scheme either with your mmu or with pci windowing into the perpherals.  to the pain point of on most computers you throw away 1GB or 2GB of the ram you purchased so the pcie has a place to sit, the last few years the bioses on wintel machines are allowing for high 2GB windows so that does not throw away a GB.  but now you know why when you bought 4gb you only got 3 or bought 16 you only got 15.

short answer segment shifted left 4 plus offset is 20 bits which is 1MB of addressable space.  this tied directly to 20 address pins on the processor.  the data bus was either 8 (8088) or 16 (8086) bits, but internally it was 16 bits, for the 8088 the hardware would do two cycles for you to collect each half of the 16 bit word. a few more control signals power and clock and that was pretty much the entire pinout of the part.  the ram was essentially zero wait state so you had to speed match your memory and processor or at least buy ram that was at or faster than the processor.

Answer (score 0):

16 bit DOS used a 20 bit addressing scheme, which only allows up to 1 MB of memory (RAM) to be accessed. There were, however, things called "DOS Extenders" available, which allowed 16 bit DOS to access more memory.